# How to change TTLauncherItem's text label frame/position

Tags: iphone, ios, three20, ttlauncheritem

I need a custom TTLauncherItem displaying the text on to of the image.
Is there a way to get this working?

Default looks like:

```
+----+
|    |
+----+
 text
```

And I want it to be like this:

```
+----+
|text|
+----+
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you can modify the image parameter in the TTLauncherItem init function.

```
[[[TTLauncherItem alloc] initWithTitle:@":)"
      image:nil
      URL:@"tt://tabBarTest" canDelete:NO] autorelease]
```

Comment: That's not what he asked. He wants to change the position of the title label relative to the image, but he still wants the image.